# Mobile payment app: infringement of Apple's IAP guideline?

Tags: business

I just read about Apple's [App Store Review Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase):

> Apps may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than IAP.

What's the scope of this requirement? Does it only apply to payment to `unlock features or functionality within your app` or all payment behavior? Do online payment apps (Line Pay, Alipay) violate this guideline? After all, their sole purpose is to direct customers to their own payment mechanism.

Comment: I believe you'd be best off asking Apple on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read *the whole* review guidelines. You missed out on some important information.

There are two kinds of purchases: Purchases that end up on the customer's mobile device, and purchases that end up elsewhere. For example, if you buy an eBook, it ends up on your device. If you buy a physical book, it ends up on your physical bookshelf.

There are different rules depending on what kind of purchase it is. For the first kind of purchases, you *must* use IAP. For the second kind of purchases, you *may not* use IAP. So the sites that you mention are not only Ok not using IAP, if they had apps (I didn't check) those apps would be rejected if they did use IAP.

Comment: Ahh yes I found the section you referred to, and it's not far away from the section in my post... For other people's reference, here's the [link](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#physical-goods-and-services) to it.